# jQuery/CSS Gallery/Slideshow How to limit thumbnail scroll to visible area

Tags: jquery, css, gallery

Okay, have a gallery slideshow feature where the selected thumbnail's img source will be shown in the main image container.

I think I can make that part work. My problem right now is trying to define the thumbnail scrolling area - I want it showing thumbnails and not blank spaces.

Here is the jQuery:

```
function thumbs_slide(){
            var more_thumbs = jQuery('.more-thumbs');
            var less_thumbs = jQuery('.less-thumbs');
            var thumbnails = jQuery('.thumb-outer-container .thumbnails');
            var more_scroll = '-100%';
            var less_scroll = '100%';
            var out_scroll = thumbnails.css('top');

            more_thumbs.hover(function(){
                thumbnails.css('top',more_scroll)
            },function(){
                out_scroll = thumbnails.css('top');
                thumbnails.css('top',out_scroll);                   
            })

            less_thumbs.hover(function(){
                thumbnails.css('top',less_scroll);
            },function(){
                out_scroll = thumbnails.css('top');
                thumbnails.css('top',out_scroll);
            })
        }

        thumbs_slide();
```

CSS:

```
.single-product .load .images .thumb-outer-container {
float: right;
width: 20%;
max-width: 200px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;


.thumb-outer-container .thumbnails {
-moz-transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.thumb-outer-container .more-thumbs,
 .thumb-outer-container .less-thumbs {
opacity: .85;
position: absolute;
z-index: 99;
right: 0;
left: 0;
height: 50%;

text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;

-moz-transition: all .05s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all .05s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .05s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all .05s ease-in-out;
transition: all .05s ease-in-out;
}

.more-thumbs {
top: 0;
}

.more-thumbs::after {
    content: '\f077';
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid currentColor;
    background-color: rgba(249,249,249,.95);
    color: rgba(0,174,239,1);
}

.less-thumbs {
bottom: 0;
}

.less-thumbs::after {
    content: '\f078';
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid currentColor;
    background-color: rgba(249,249,249,.95);
    color: rgba(0,174,239,1);
}

.thumb-outer-container .more-thumbs:hover,
.thumb-outer-container .more-thumbs:focus,
.thumb-outer-container .less-thumbs:hover,
.thumb-outer-container .less-thumbs:focus {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

.single-product .load .images img {
border: 0;
}

.single-product .load .images .thumbnails {
padding-top: 0 !important;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
}

.single-product .load .images .thumbnails a {
margin: 0 0 1px !important;
padding: 0 !important;
border: 0;
float: left !important;
display: inline-block !important;
width: 100% !important;
max-width: 200px !important;
}

.single-product .load .images .thumbnails a:hover,
.single-product .load .images .thumbnails a:focus {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

It's a WP site, I can add more code if needed, but I believe it is something needed in my jQuery.

Sample link: http://www.dev.mediaworksweb.com/beamimaging-wp/product/phosphor-screens/  -> gallery tab

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

One way of solving this would be to bind a `click` event to each image in the thumbnail slider that would change the main image when clicked. This would be done similar to the following:

```
$('.thumbnails a img').click(function() {
  $(".woocommerce-main-image").attr("src", this.attr("src"));
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

My answer ended up being in the jQuery variables.

Changed less_scroll from '100%' to '0';

```
    var more_scroll = '-100%';
    var less_scroll = '0';
```